# connecting clients to server with emulator on different computers

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-emulator

I am writing an application that communicates using sockets. I have a server running on one android emulator on a computer, then i have 2 other clients running on android emulators on 2 other computers. I am trying to get the 2 clients to connect to the server.

This works when i run the server and clients on the same computer, but when i attempt to do this on the same wifi network and on separate computers it gives me the following error. The client and server code is posted below. A lot is stripped out just to show the important stuff. Also, after the server starts i telnet into the server and run these commands `redir add tcp:5000:6000` (i have also tried without doing the `redir` but it still says the same thing). Then i start the clients and get the error. Thanks for the help!

Both the 5000 port and 6000 port are open on my router. And i have windows firewall disabled on the computer hosting the server.

```
11-27 18:54:02.274: W/ActivityManager(60): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{44cf0a30 school.cpe434.ClassAidClient/school.cpe434.ClassAid.ClassAidClient4Activity}
11-27 18:57:02.424: W/System.err(205): java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out
11-27 18:57:02.454: W/System.err(205):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connectSocketImpl(Native Method)
11-27 18:57:02.454: W/System.err(205):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(OSNetworkSystem.java:114)
11-27 18:57:02.465: W/System.err(205):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:245)
11-27 18:57:02.465: W/System.err(205):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:220)
11-27 18:57:02.465: W/System.err(205):  at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:780)
11-27 18:57:02.465: W/System.err(205):  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:314)
11-27 18:57:02.465: W/System.err(205):  at school.cpe434.ClassAid.ClassAidClient4Activity.onCreate(ClassAidClient4Activity.java:102)
11-27 18:57:02.474: W/System.err(205):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-27 18:57:02.474: W/System.err(205):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
11-27 18:57:02.474: W/System.err(205):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
11-27 18:57:02.474: W/System.err(205):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
11-27 18:57:02.474: W/System.err(205):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
11-27 18:57:02.474: W/System.err(205):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-27 18:57:02.474: W/System.err(205):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-27 18:57:02.486: W/System.err(205):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
11-27 18:57:02.486: W/System.err(205):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 18:57:02.486: W/System.err(205):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-27 18:57:02.486: W/System.err(205):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
11-27 18:57:02.486: W/System.err(205):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
11-27 18:57:02.486: W/System.err(205):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

**The server code**

```
public class ClassAidServer4Activity extends Activity {

    ServerSocket ss = null;
    String mClientMsg = "";
    String mClientExtraMsg = "";
    Thread myCommsThread = null;
    public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText("Nothing from client yet");
        this.myCommsThread = new Thread(new CommsThread());
        this.myCommsThread.start();
    }

    class CommsThread implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            //         Socket s = null;
            try {
                ss = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT );
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            while(true) {
                try {


                    Socket socket = ss.accept();
                    connectedDeviceCount++;

                    Thread lThread = new Thread(new ListeningThread(socket));
                    lThread.start();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        }
    }

    class ListeningThread implements Runnable {

        private Socket s = null;

        public ListeningThread(Socket socket) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.s = socket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                Message m = new Message();
                //              m.what = QUESTION_ID;
                try {
                    if (s == null)
                        s = ss.accept();
                    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                    String st = null;
                    st = input.readLine();
                    String[] temp = parseReadMessage(st);
                    mClientMsg = temp[1];
                    if(temp.length > 2) {
                        mClientExtraMsg = temp[2];
                    }

                    m.what = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
                    myUpdateHandler.sendMessage(m);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

---

**The client code**

```
public class ClassAidClient4Activity extends Activity {

    //telnet localhost 5554
    //redir add tcp:5000:6000
    private Socket socket;
       private String serverIpAddress = "192.168.1.102";
    // if "redir add" is disabled this should be 6000
    private static final int REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT = 5000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            mQuestionAdapter.add("UnknownHostException");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            mQuestionAdapter.add("IOException");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to create a proxy. I used [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990565/connecting-real-device-to-android-emulator) as a reference. And heavily modified [this code](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/Asimpleproxyserver.htm) to work for multiple connections. It is working now. HOORAY!