# Google Play services ButtonClicker app issue with multiplayer mode

Tags: google-play-services

I test [ButtonClicker](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples) app, so I publish it on Google Play under my dev account https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dimakoles.clickbutton

Now I try to play in multiplayer mode ("Quick game" button) and get the problem. In screenshot below you can see waiting room screen where "Start Playing" menu option is inactive on both devices while two players already meet one another

[image: screenshot]

I also provide logs with principle method invocations on both devices

**First device:**

1) getGamesClient().createRoom(config);

2) onRoomCreated

3) startActivityForResult(getGamesClient().getRealTimeWaitingRoomIntent(room, 2), RC_WAITING_ROOM);

**Second device:**

1) getGamesClient().createRoom(config);

**First device:**

4) onPeerJoined

5) onRoomConnecting

**Second device:**

2) onRoomCreated

3) startActivityForResult(getGamesClient().getRealTimeWaitingRoomIntent(room, 2), RC_WAITING_ROOM);

4) onPeerJoined

5) onRoomConnecting

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a network issue. The callback that signals that the room is ready for playing is `onRoomConnected()`. It looks like your connection is going all the way up to `onRoomConnecting()` but doesn't proceed any further. The connectivity is a P2P network so there must be something preventing the two devices from communicating properly. I'd check network settings (NAT, etc) to make sure that you're in an environment where one device can actually open a socket to the other device directly.

It looks like you're running one of the apps in an emulated environment... maybe the networking emulation isn't properly configured?

Comment: But there is no way to connect emulator to real device directly. As mentioned there http://stackoverflow.com/a/4455447/909169 should I use proxy?

Comment: fyi https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/ECM93R2YUrw/vRMlvHwwH8UJ